# SELECT .. SELECT in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, logical-operators

I am trying to write a query for mysql `(Search Module)` where I am facing difficulties because of the select operation to be carried out inside same table.

My Query:

```
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user_name` like '%TOM%' OR `user_name` like '%AN%' 
and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-02-31 23:59:59')
    OR
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user_name` like '%PHP%' OR `user_name` like '%BA%' 
and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-02-01 00:00:00' and '2013-03-31 23:59:59')
    AND
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user_name` like '%SUN%' OR `user_name` like '%MOON%' 
and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' and '2013-04-31 23:59:59') 
    NAND
(SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user_name` like '%RAJ%' OR `user_name` like '%MUTH%' 
and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' and '2013-06-31 23:59:59') 
    NOR
 (SELECT * FROM user WHERE `user_name` like '%BAG%' OR `user_name` like '%LAP%'
 and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' and '2013-07-31 23:59:59')
```

The above mentioned query is my scenario.. Where this cannot be changed, I am trying to write a Query for this.

## Note:

1. The above query execute in a single table.
2. **OR, NAND, NOR, AND** operation can be inter-changed with according to the situation.
3. It depends with the user, how he needs to search.

I tried many ways to achieve the logic but I am facing issues in all phases.

Check my try:
[MySQL IN BETWEEN with no condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040898/mysql-in-between-with-no-condition)
[Doctrine Query from Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979669/doctrine-query-from-mysql)
[Select Query with OR and NAND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940484/select-query-with-or-and-nand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAND and NOR operations can be done as follows in SQL: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438440/mysql-nand-nor-operations-in-queries)

Just edit the following query as you need it.

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE 
(`user_name` like '%TOM%' OR `user_name` like '%AN%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-01-01 00:00:00' and '2013-02-31 23:59:59') OR
NOT ( --NOR
   (`user_name` like '%PHP%' OR `user_name` like '%BA%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-02-01 00:00:00' and '2013-03-31 23:59:59') OR
   (`user_name` like '%SUN%' OR `user_name` like '%MOON%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-03-01 00:00:00' and '2013-04-31 23:59:59')
) OR
NOT ( --NAND
   (`user_name` like '%RAJ%' OR `user_name` like '%MUTH%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' and '2013-06-31 23:59:59') AND
   (`user_name` like '%BAG%' OR `user_name` like '%LAP%' and `login_datetime` BETWEEN '2013-05-01 00:00:00' and '2013-07-31 23:59:59')
)
```

In the above example all records are returned where the condition between the first parenthesises is true OR (2nd condition NOR 3rd condition) OR (4th condition NAND 5th condition).

*NOTE*: *condition* refers to the clauses between parenthesises.

Comment: NAND and NOR operations link was my previous question where I can achieve the operations but when it comes with multiple queries it is not working...

Comment: Can you help me in converting this MySQL in to Doctrine.. Structure.